# Calling Toolbar's tool in to Graphical modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I need to use the "Merge selected features" tool from "Advanced digitizing toolbar" in my QGIS model. I am not sure how to call tools.

Comment: what do you mean with "call tools"?